# How to apply transformation effects using JavaScript to an element multiple times on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, translate

I am trying to build a small game in which I require an element to be moved depending on user clicks. I am facing problem using transformation translate when user clicks a button. The transformation is happening only once. Also the "**ontransitionend**" event is also called once. Overall, the change is happening just the first time the user clicks the button. The following code shows a short preview of what I am trying to achieve:

The following is the code:

```js
var x=document.getElementById("circle")
x.style.top="140px"
var deltaY=40; 
var deltaX=40;
var times=0; 
// x.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
//   x.style.top=(200-times*deltaY)+"px";
//   console.log("end")
// }) 
function moveUp(){ 
  if (!x.currentDeltaY) {
    x.currentDeltaY = 0;
  }

  x.currentDeltaY = x.currentDeltaY + deltaY;

  times=times+1;
  x.style.transition = "transform 0.2s"; 
  x.style.transform="translateY(-"+x.currentDeltaY +"px)"
  
}

function moveR(){ 
  if (!x.currentDeltaX) {
    x.currentDeltaX = 0;
  }

  x.currentDeltaX = x.currentDeltaX + deltaX;

  times=times+1;
  x.style.transition = "transform 0.2s"; 
  x.style.transform="translateX("+x.currentDeltaX+"px)"
  // x.style.top = deltay+" px";  

}
```

```css
#circle{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:seagreen;
  border-radius:50%;
  // top:200px;
  left:140px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moveUp()">Move Up</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moveR()">Move Right</button>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Could anybody help me how to achieve the translation transformation on every user click? Here is the pen to the code:

https://codepen.io/aayush612/pen/NWxxpZr?editors=0101

PS: I am very new to Javascript. Please bear with me:)

**Thanks a lot in advance!!**

**Edit**:

As suggested by JPortillo, his suggestion works but when extended this thing to two dimensions is causing weird behavior. I have updated the Copdepen link with another button which should move the circle to right. I am also open to suggestions on other ways we could tackle this problem( of moving a point based on user input in 2d).Kindly suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are moving the element to a different position, your best bet is changing the element CSS position to absolute and use top and left. I wonder if CSS transform/translate only change the position visually and not logically -can you try clicking on the original position of the object to see if it moves further?-

Comment: I just noticed something. The translation you are applying is anchored to the original position. You need to keep a variable that holds the current translation, and add movement based on the current position. "translate(0,-"+(currentDeltaY+deltaY)+"px)"

Answer (score 0):

Disregard my first comment, the problem is what I called out on my second one. The CSS transform will modify the position based on the original rendering position. That said, the code below should be closer to what you are looking for.

I just updated my response based on your question below. The problem is that `circle.style.transform` needs to hold both vertical and horizontal transformations. In your code, when you move the object vertically, you are replacing the horizontal translation for a vertical translation, and vice versa. Since translations are relative to the objects original position, it moves back. Below an updated script that takes care of everything.

```js
var circle=document.getElementById("circle")
var deltaY=40; 
var deltaX=40;
var times=0; 

function move(x, y) {
  if (!circle.currentDeltaX) {
    circle.currentDeltaX = 0;
  }
  
  if (!circle.currentDeltaY) {
    circle.currentDeltaY = 0;
  }
  
  if (x) {
    circle.currentDeltaX = circle.currentDeltaX + x;
  }
  
  if (y) {
    circle.currentDeltaY = circle.currentDeltaY + y;
  }
  
  circle.style.transform="translate(" + circle.currentDeltaX + "px, " + circle.currentDeltaY + "px)";
}

function moveUp(){ 
  move(0, -deltaY);
}

function moveDown(){ 
  move(0, deltaY);
}

function moveRight(){ 
  move(deltaX, 0);
}

function moveLeft(){ 
  move(-deltaX, 0);
}
```

```css
#circle{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:seagreen;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:140px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moveUp()">Move Up</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moveDown()">Move Down</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moveRight()">Move Right</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moveLeft()">Move Left</button>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for time and suggestion J, your code block works!! Also, could you please look at the edit I have just made. I feel I should have mentioned that earlier about this whole thing being a 2D setup. Again, Thanks a lot!